# CGAL: How can I create a surface mesh that fills a bordering curve?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, surface, triangulation

I have a vector of segments which is a result of a 2D alpha shape and I'm looking to first create a triangulation of a 2D surface enclosing that shape. Ultimately I'd then like to extrude the resulting surface.

Are there any examples or functions built for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2D contours that you would like to triangulate, you can use a constrained Delaunay triangulation to triangulate it. See [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title30) that is used to triangulate polygons (with holes).

About the extrusion, you'll need to convert your point to 3D points and then you can use the function [`extrude_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html#ga6cf0f4aaf1f304d129d76b9d20a4e909).

Comment: Won't I need to do more than just convert my 2D points to 3D points? I'll need to keep the triangles of the 2D triangulation.

Comment: There is a way using `Face_filtered_graph` to directly use the CDT but the simplest solution is to copy/paste/adapt the code of `cdt2_to_face_graph()` from [this plugin](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polyhedron/demo/Polyhedron/Plugins/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_plugin.cpp#L113) to create a `Surface_mesh` and use it for the extrusion.

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? The function is rather straight forward. Is it a matter of the types you used?